# Notwithstanding the craziness

Tags: single-word-requests

I find it really amusing when other people misuse words but my sense of humor fails when it's me. I have always used "notwithstanding" to mean "assuming that A doesn't impact B". For example

*The delivery will be on time, notwithstanding the holiday.*

To me, this meant, *the delivery should be on time, but you never know what impact the holiday will have on it.*

Turns out, *notwithstanding* means almost the opposite: *in spite of, regardless of*.

So my question is, what word should I be using instead?

Comment: You've been using it wrong.  "Notwithstanding" means "even though X might occur/be present".  For your meaning I would probably use "assuming that X does not interfere", or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Permitting** comes to mind. It's an established idiom with, for instance, *weather*, as [the Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Weather+Permitting) shows:

> weather permitting
>
> Fig. if the weather allows it. Weather permitting, we will be there on time. The plane lands at midnight, weather permitting.

If you don't want to mention any specific reasons why something might not happen, you could use the good old [deo volente](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deo%20volente).

Comment: Or, "Lord willin' and the crik don't rise."

Comment: @HotLicks But of course that phrase should only be reserved for the most formal of contexts; official documents, letters of recommendation, legal briefs.

Comment: Thanks @oerkelens. It's maddening when I develop a linguistic flatspot like this. Permitting is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Terry: don't worry, you're not alone. There are times I feel the tip of my tongue must contain half the OED for the words that will not come to mind :)